# How to set route in Laravel for SEO?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I had set my route like this

```
Route::get('teacher-jobs/{subject}/{city}','TeacherJobsController@index');
```

Resulting in this url: `https://www.abcde.com/teacher-jobs/computer/patna`. Is there any disadvantage to set like this the above way?

Is there any advantage in SEO if my route will be like this:

```
Route::get('{subject}- teacher-jobs-in- {city}','TeacherJobsController@index');
```

resulting in `https://www.abcde.com/computer-teacher-jobs-in-patna`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been blogging before and had a fair share of SEO knowledge.

The latter approach is the better way to do this.

My basis is the non other than Google's own blogging platform "Blogger".

On Blogger, you can customize your own url slug. If you choose to customize it, a textbox will appear, and on that textbox a suggestion url will appear.

So if your blog title is **Summer Vacation In Tokyo Japan**, it will have a suggestion of `summer-vacation-in-tokyo-japan` and not `summer/vacation/in/tokyo/japan`.

Hope this helps.